# Why is Visual Studio rewriting my member-dereference to GetComponent<>()?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the program to detect the `tag` of a specific item that the player is colliding with.

My code is

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(PlayerCollision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "ground")
        {
            print("You hit the ground");
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio keeps changing

```
if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "ground"
```

to

```
if (collisionInfo.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "ground")
```

My question is either how do I get the program to detect what the player is colliding with?

and

Why does Visual Studio keep changing my code?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't change or rewrite code by itself (at least, not like that): you have to explicitly opt-in to use a "code-fix" via a drop-down menu. Do you have any VS extensions installed? What version of VS are you using?

Comment: What is the type of `collisionInfo.collider`? I don't see it defined in the `class PlayerCollision` you posted (nor is it in `MonoBehaviour`).

Comment: @Dai This is my first day using unity and c# so I'm not sure how to answer that can you dumb it down for me

Comment: Can you post a screen-recording or video that shows you typing in that C# code and VS changing your code without you asking?

Comment: @DaiI'm so sorry but now the code isn't changing itself it gives me the error Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error    ```CS0619    'Component.collider' is obsolete: 'Property collider has been deprecated. Use GetComponent<Collider>() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'    Assembly-CSharp    C:\Users\slayp\Desktop\Making unity stuff\New Unity Project\Assets\Collision.cs    7    Active```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)`, then you can do `if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))`

Answer (score 1):

Your type `PlayerCollision` inherits from [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) which inherits from [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which finally inherits from [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html)

Here there is/was the **obsolete/now deprecated** property [`Component.collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-collider.html) which states

> CS0619    'Component.collider' is obsolete: 'Property collider has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead

Your Visual Studio seems to have some setting somewhere to automatically apply such a change recommended by obsolete code. Maybe this is even done by the `Visual Studio Tools for Unity` itself.

---

However, all this wouldn't even be a thing if you used the correct signature:

**It is [`OnCollisionEnter(Collision)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html) not `OnCollisionEnter(PlayerCollision)`!**

```
private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if(collisionInfo.collider.CompareTag("ground")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**If** for what ever strange reason you did not mean the Unity built-in message but rather actually want a method with the signature `OnCollisionEnter(PlayerCollision)` (which seems not the case here, just for completeness) then you should either chose a different name or simply use

```
collisionInfo.gameObject.CompareTag("ground")
```

which wouldn't even cause that issue since both `Collision` and `Component` have a property `.gameObject` ;)

---

In general you should prefer using [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CompareTag.html) instead of directly string compare `==`. `CompareTag` throws an error if you pass a misspelled / non-existent tag while the latter simply silently fails making your Debugging live unnecessarily harder.